# Alternative to RSA encryption in java

Tags: object, encryption, size, key, rsa

RSA encryption system with key size 1024 has a size limitation of 117bytes which can be used for encryption. This is for encrypting objects. Can any one suggest an alternative solution??

Comment: [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

Answer (score 1):

encrypt the objects using a symmetric algorithm like AES, then encrypt the key you used to encrypt the objects using RSA.  This will give you the benefits of RSA/Public Key Crypto, but the freedom to encrypt more data than the size of the RSA key.

for what its worth, this is the sort of scheme that most Public Key Crypto Protocols use (like PGP/GPG)

Answer (score 1):

Typically one encrypts and authenticates bulk data using a symmetric cipher such as TripleDES, AES, or Camellia. Since you want to make sure the data is not tampered, pick a mode like GCM or EAX over modes like CBC (paired with a separate authentication primitive) if possible. One then encrypts the symmetric key using the public/private key pair.

You can break up a large message into smaller messages and then encrypt the smaller messages. In this case, you are operating the asymmetric cipher (RSA) in ECB mode (if I recall correctly). The [Handbook of Applied Cryptography (HAC)](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) warns against the practice.

Also, without going into too much detail, try to match security levels. So if you are using AES-128, then use a RSA moduli with 3072-bits. As a counterpoint, many don't see the need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into that limit because 1024 is the number of bits. Divide it by 8 and you get 128. Then subtract 11 from that since PKCS#1 padding is being used and you get your number - 117.

Anyway, as others have noted, what's usually done is that you encrypt a randomly generated symmetric key and then use that to encrypt / decrypt stuff.